# Installing Windows SQL Express Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, windows

I am having an issue installing Windows SQL Express Server 2016, when I try to run setup.exe, it tells me that:

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows that you are running. Check your computer's system to see whether you need x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of this program, then contact the software publisher"

I am running Windows 7, 32-bit, but I was never prompted to select this either from Microsoft's website or from the installer that I downloaded, so I assumed it automatically figured it out. Where can I get the 32-bit version?

Comment: Installation of SQL Server 2016 is supported on x64 processors only. It is no longer supported on x86 processors. In addition Windows 7 is not supported.

Comment: Do you know of any substitutes? I needed it for a course on T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last SQL Server that still support Windows 7 is [SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx). The next version, SQL Server 2014, already [requires Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx). So you'll have to use SQL Server Express 2012.

Comment: Are the differences between SQL Express Server 2012 and 2016 significant in terms of the use of T-SQL? I am thinking I will just download the 2012 server and see if I can complete the assignments, but if the differences are significant, another option is to complete the assignments through Azure.

Comment: SQL Server Express 2016 **SP1** is significantly different, because of this announcement: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/ . With 2016 SP1 you get most of the enterprise features, like columnstores and partitioning, in *every* edition including Express. With 2012 you'll get only the 'classic' T-SQL features (tables, indexes, stored procedures etc).